# IE9 RTL background positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, right-to-left

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bHRVe/

A sprite is being used for the arrow. The background position is fine in Firefox and IE8:

[image: FF Screenshot]

However, the RTL direction seems to be throwing off IE9, the arrow is no longer there:

[image: IE9 Screenshot]

If I change the positioning from `left -52px` to `right -52px`, then it displays correctly in IE9 but breaks in other browsers.

Is there any way to fix this using the same CSS? (without conditionals or hacks)

Comment: Not against it at all, but cannot feasibly use it for this particular project. Would be a last resort option.

Comment: Is there any reasoning as to why IE9 interprets background-position in RTL layouts differently? I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your css a little bit:

```
.button span {
    background: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/16716yb.png") no-repeat scroll left -52px transparent;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    direction: rtl;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/bHRVe/5/). Tested and working in IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera :)

Comment: I came up with exactly the same css. You need to add width, height and  display properties. IE is not good at 'guessing' dimensions, and the span element might behave unexpectedly if its' display is not set.

Comment: This would have been my first suggestion too - IE really needs anything out of the ordinary to be clearly defined. When it starts having to work things out for itself things can get weird.  Side note - do you use any kind of reset CSS?

Comment: Yes, I do, but it's kind a global reset, not specifically for IE.

Comment: I am an actual idiot for not even considering placing dimensions on the arrow span. Accepted for having the least amount of change from my original CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is pure css based solution of your problem:

**css:**

```
.button span {
    background: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/16716yb.png") no-repeat 0 -52px;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 5px;
    direction: rtl;
    width:4px;
    height:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML:**

**Note:** It is good practice if you put space (`&nbsp;`) in empty element because some time it helps in browser compatibility.

```
<a class="button" href="#">
    <b>تم, غزو عل جنوب</b>
    <br/>
    <u>ب ان. Testما وص</u>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</a>
```

**Additional Note:** By Default `<span>` and `<a>` elements are inline elements. we need to make them `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` using css as per our need.

In your case you can use `display:block;` also but then you need to add `float:left` also to make the span at proper place.

**Screen Shot:** IE9

[image]